# I'm making a simple Financial ledger, but I made a function of input and search, but it's blocked in the deletion and correction section

Tags: c

```
#define SIZE 1024
char buffer[SIZE];
char word[1024];

FILE* ab; // file pointer

int add(FILE* ab)
{
printf("quit:ctrl + z\n");

fseek(ab, 0, SEEK_SET);

while (fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin) != 0)
    fputs(buffer, ab);
}
```

Use the add function to enter it into a text file.

```
void change(FILE* ab)
{
char name[SIZE], fname[SIZE], tmp[SIZE];
struct Product P;

}
```

First of all, I have a approximate frame, but i can't proceed here, and this code is a code that reads the text file and corrects the part you want.

```
void delete(FILE* ab)
{
char delname[SIZE];
char fname[SIZE];
char buffer[SIZE];
FILE* fp;

printf("input file name :");// d:\\test\\baby.txt
scanf("%s", fname);

printf("remove contents: ");
gets_s(delname, SIZE);

while (1)
{
    fscanf(ab, "%s %d", buffer, fname);
    if (feof(ab))
        break;
    


if (!strcmp(buffer, delname))
        {   
            fputs(" ", ab);
        }
}
printf("remove complete");
}
```

I don't know how to make the code for the modification part, and I'd appreciate it if you could fix the deletion part a little bit here.

Comment: Why do you `fscanf` for the `fname` using the `%d` type specifier?

Comment: " if you could fix the deletion part a little bit here." --> enable all compiler warnings ( or use a better compiler)  That saves us all time.

Comment: To import and enter a file - andy sukowski-bang

Comment: @gndn1004 The `%d` specifier is meant for the `int` datatype. You need the `%s` or the `%[^\n]` specifier for a string.